# Static files not loading on one template but loading on another

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I got a template from online, and managed to get the CSS and JS working with one of my HTML templates; but for another one, the same CSS/JS won't load despite the code being identical.

Here is my settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

This is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "about.html", {})
 
def contact(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    return render(request, "contact.html", {})

def work(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    return render(request, "work.html", {})
```

Here are my URL Patterns:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages.views import home_view
from pages.views import contact
from pages.views import work
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view , name='home'), 
    path('contact/', contact, name = 'contact' ),
    path('work/', work, name = 'work'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here is the CSS of my template that works; I had to hard code it because the static tag wouldn't work for some reason:

```
{ % load static %}

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Mighty &mdash; Website Template by Colorlib</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href = https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,700  rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href= 'static/fonts/icomoon/style.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/owl.carousel.min.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/owl.theme.default.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/aos.css'>

    <!-- MAIN CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= 'static/css/style.css'>
```

And here is the CSS portion of the template that does not work:

```
{ % load static % }
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Mighty &mdash; Website Template by Colorlib</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/fonts/icomoon/style.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/owl.carousel.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/owl.theme.default.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/aos.css'>

    <!-- MAIN CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='static/css/style.css'>
```

Comment: it works for home and not for other I suppose?

Comment: @iklinac         Yeah the home view works but the other views don't, and for some reason anything beside hard coding it also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

settings.py :

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    ]
    
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
```

Each file write like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have paths without starting /

which then appends path to already existing path like

```
lala.la/contact/static/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css'
```

just change them to root paths

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css'>
```

Also it would be wise to set static settings correctly using [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I had set my settings correctly though, I followed some different tutorials online